# Grouping words based on last letter

Tags: python

I am working on a project where I need to group words imported from text file based on last letter in the word. This is what I have so far but I can't get it to work.

```
import string
try:
hd=open('mars.txt','r')
except Exception as e:
print(e)
for line in hd:
    line = line.strip()
    line = line.lower()
    words = line.split(' ')
lowercase = string.ascii_lowercase
data = {lowercase[:i] for i in range(26)}


for character in sorted(data.keys()):
if len(data[character])!=0:
    a.append(sorted(data[character]))
```

I was trying to use dictionary but it doesn't seem to work.
Any help will be appreciated.

**EDIT**

Input example:

```
today is a very good, cold day
```

Output:

```
[today,very,day],[good,cold],[is],[a]
```

Comment: Can you add to your question an example of the input and an example result, please?

Comment: Just added it to the question. Input example: today is a very good, cold day Output: [today,very,day],[good,cold],[is],[a]

Comment: Please, share a sample of your data. I can propose a new algorithm which is more simple.

Answer (score 0):

say you have a list of string elements called `m_list`, sort it by the last char, and then group them by the last element:

```
import itertools
m_list = ['aa', 'ba', 'ca', 'bb', 'cb', 'db', 'ac', 'bc', 'dc', '']
m_list = [item for item in m_list if item]
m_list.sort(key = lambda x: x[-1])
grouped_list = [list(group) for key, group in itertools.groupby(m_list, lambda x: x[-1])]
print(grouped_list)
```

output:

```
[['aa', 'ba', 'ca'], ['bb', 'cb', 'db'], ['ac', 'bc', 'dc']]
```

Note: this solution assume that the string elements are at least 1 char long, I recommend you to filter empty string, edited to avoid future potentially bugs

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> import re
>>>
>>> d = defaultdict(list)
>>> with open('mars.txt') as f:
...     for line in f:
...         words = re.findall(r'\w+', line.lower())
...         if not words:
...             continue
...         for word in words:
...             d[word[-1]].append(word)
...
>>> d
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'y': ['today', 'very', 'day'], 's': ['is'], 'a': ['a'], 'd': ['good', 'cold']})
>>> d['d']
['good', 'cold']
```

```
$ cat mars.txt 
today is

A 
very good,
cold DAY
```